# Ubuntu 16.04 Apache2 PHP7.0 doesn't interpret php commands

Tags: apache, php-7, ubuntu-16.04

I searched the web and found that many people have issues with php7 on Ubuntu 16.04 but I have a slightly different experience.

Problem in short: I upgraded from 12.04 to (first to 14.04) 16.04 and now everything works except Apache2 with PHP7.

The problem: When I create php file like

```
Hello
<?
echo " World!";
?>
```

and access it through the browser, the browser renders the "Hello" but not the "World". So basically Apache knows that it's a php file (otherwise the file would be downloaded instead of shown) but doesnt interpret it.
Oh and it doesn't show the php code either (this is what's different in my problem compared to other asked questions).

I had PHP7 installed from a different ppa (ondrej) before but that also didn't work. I completely removed all the packages and PPAs from my sources and now I have only my Ubuntu sources left, I also completely purged all php and apache related packages, including any config under /etc/apache2 and /etc/php. This includes:

- php*
- php7.0*
- libapache2-mod-php7.0
- libapache2-mod-php
- apache2*

I even removed the apt cache with `apt-get clean` and `apt-get autoclean`.

After I purged everything I reinstalled apache and php via

```
apt install apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0
```

I checked the mods enabled, php7.0 is enabled, restarted apache, even restarted the whole machine just to be sure but I can't get it to work.

Please don't tell me to reinstall Ubuntu because I want to understand what the problem is instead of just taking the easy way out, also everything else runs fine and I really, really don't want to reinstall all other software again since this is my development machine.
Is there any config file I have overlooked? I mean I completely purged the packages and the configs. /etc/apache2 and /etc/php were properly deleted after the purge.

Oh and also strange: Since the Update I cannot access files without the file extension. Before http://localhost/info would bring me to http://localhost/info.php automatically. Any hints?

Comment: Did you enable short tags? `<?` won't work unless you do.

Comment: @MarcB You gotta be kidding me. You're right.
Thanks Ubuntu package. Default value is "On" and still they deliver the config with it set to "Off". Didn't think about it since in 12.04 this worked out of the box.
For all others experiencing this problem:
Set `short_open_tag = On` in /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

Consider upgrading your comment to an answer, as short as it might be.

Comment: Oh and still, I can't get apache to interpret localhost/info as localhost/info.php, even with mod rewrite and multiviews

Comment: Nvm, got that too. MultiViews doesn't default to "Any" anymore.
Damn, that was a lot of changes, I shouldn't skip so many versions next time.